# What part of speech are the words the, a, my, that, your, each, every, etc, or what category do they fall under?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What part of speech are

- the
- a
- my
- that
- your
- each
- every

etc, or what category do they fall under?

The reason I am asking this is that I am programming a sentence generator, and my sentence structure looks a bit like this:

```
[noundesc] [adj][0 to 2] [noun] [verb-ed]or[verb-s] [noundesc] [adj][0 to 2] [noun]
```

Actually, this is just one of the sentence variations, but I'm just using it as an example. Right now I'm referring to them as "noundesc"s (short for "noun describers"), because I don't have a good name.

I have found that "this," "that," "these," and "those" are called *demostrative pronouns*, but that does not encompass all of these words.

What is a name for these types of words? I need a name so I can search for a list of them, which I will use in my sentence generator. Are these just special kinds of adjectives, and if so, is there any special name for them?

Comment: @down/close voter: how is this general reference? I tried searching but could not find anything (other than demonstrative pronouns)

Comment: Doorknob, I don't want to seem rude, but you seem to have embarked on this without doing any basic research. There are any number of modern grammars available.

Comment: @ColinFine I understand where you're coming from (10k+ user on SO myself), but I don't really see where I could have found this. Could you point me to a search or a resource where I could have found what these are called, so I can use it in the future?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts_of_speech#Functional_classification

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks; what Google search did you use to find that? I couldn't find any pages like that...

Comment: I doubt very much ColinFine needed to do a Google research, he probably eats grammar for breakfast :) Here is a comprehensive [list of grammatical terms](http://www.dailygrammar.com/glossary.html), which you might find useful or mind boggling, but it's not a bad place to start from.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not everyone eats grammar even for a feast, esp., a number of grammars at one sitting.

Comment: @ColinFine I'm sure you meant a number of resources on modern English grammar. And how does that link help in any way, please?

Comment: @Kris: Well, I didn't have just English in mind when I wrote the first comment.The link was a response to Doorknob's request for a resource where he could have found what these are called. I went to Wikipedia and search for "Parts of speech".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are **[determiners](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers)**. Determiners were traditionally classified as adjectives, but more modern theories of grammar set them aside as a separate category.

Determiners include *articles* (*a* / *an* and *the*), *demonstratives* (*this* / *these* and *that* / *those*), possessives, and quantifiers [among others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners).